# htaccess redirect each CSS URL to another CSS file

Tags: htaccess

I want to redirect every URL which ends with `.css` to a specific CSS file. This is because we are using Mouseflow for analysis and sometimes we generate a new CSS file.

Mouseflow is then trying to load the "old" CSS file from the time it is recorded, but this file does not exist anymore... so the new file hast to be loaded.

Is there something like `www.example.com/*.css` --> `www.example.com/374893.css`?

Comment: I assume you meant "rewrite" (as in an _internal URL rewrite_), as opposed to an _external_ "redirect"?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following (using mod_rewrite) near the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/374893\.css$
RewriteRule \.css$ 374893.css [L]
```

The above rewrites all requests that end in `.css` (except for `/374893.css`) to `374893.css`.

> **UPDATE:** no the css is not in the root. But do I need to name the full path? I though just matching the filename is enough

If you are editing the root `.htaccess` file and the CSS files are located in a `/styles` subdirectory then you would need to modify your directives like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/374893\.css$
RewriteRule \.css$ styles/374893.css [L]
```

This assumes the `RewriteBase` directive is either not set at all or set to `/` (a single slash). If it's set to a different location then you will *need* to prefix the `RewriteRule` *substitution* with a slash, ie. `/styles/374893.css`.

Alternatively, if all requests are also for the `/styles` subdirectory and this directory only contains `.css` files then it would be more efficient to instead create an additional `.htaccess` file at `/styles/.htaccess` with a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^374893\.css$ 374893.css [L]
```

Creating an additional `.htaccess` in this way avoids the directive being unnecessarily processed for all non-CSS requests.

Comment: I use this now but is does not work 

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/1573833767_77422c7c50808c66cb9d2b1dde821d8b\.css$
RewriteRule \.css$ 1573833767_77422c7c50808c66cb9d2b1dde821d8b.css [L]`

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Do you get an error? Undesirable output? Is your CSS file receiving the request? What response do you get? Is seemingly nothing happening? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? (It's a bit unusual that you have CSS files in the document root?)

Comment: no the css is not in the root. But do I need to name the full path? I though just matching the filename is enough

Comment: "do I need to name the full path?" - it depends, but probably _yes_. Where is this `.htaccess` file? What is the _URL_ of the requested `.css` file? And what is the _filesystem path_ of the `.css` file you want to "redirect" to?

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you add more details about your filesystem then I can be more specific in my answer. Also note that directives in `.htaccess` don't work in isolation - the order matters.